# Async TeeFilter of logback

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

I am using `TeeFilter` of **logback** to trace all HTTP requests/responses in my Spring Boot application.

**TeeFilter Bean**

```
@Bean(name = "TeeFilter")
public Filter teeFilter() {
    return new TeeFilter();
}
```

**Add context valve in embedded tomcat**

```
LogbackValve valve = new LogbackValve();
valve.setFilename("logback-access.xml");
tomcat.addContextValves(valve);
```

**logback-access.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${APP_HOME}/log/bims-http-trace.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/http-trace.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%fullRequest%n%n%fullResponse</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</configuration>
```

The above config is okay and no problem to write log in file using `FILE` appender.

But when I try to use `ASYNC` appender

```
<appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
```

I am getting the following exception

```
16:48:48,859 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[ASYNC] - Appender [ASYNC] failed to append. java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
        at java.lang.ClassCastException: ch.qos.logback.access.spi.AccessEvent cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
        at      at ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender.preprocess(AsyncAppender.java:1)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.append(AsyncAppenderBase.java:147)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:48)
        at      at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:268)
        at      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at      at 
        .......
        .......
```

**The exception is clear that I can not use ASYNC appender for this event due to class casting issue**

> My question is there any way to make the `TeeFilter` async to store in file or using logback to store HTTP trace in a file asynchronously?

Comment: I am facing this same issue now, do you find any solution yet?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't find any solution for this situation!